# How to get the newer of 2 dates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Consider 2 dates stored in 2 tables:

```
table_1: user_id data_1 update_date
table_2: user_id data_2 update_date
```

Is there a simple way to get the later of the 2 in MySQL?

If there is only one found, then it should return it.

EDIT: Added table details.

Comment: Actually, I think they do. I updated the question.

Comment: Is there a comon key between the 2 tables, is there a search condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`GREATEST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

```
SELECT GREATEST(t1.update_date, t2.update_date) AS update_date
FROM table_1 AS t1
   , table_2 AS t2
```

Your query might be more complex but that should give you the idea.

Comment: Cool, somehow I never knew about GREATEST.